# Elastic MapReduce bootstrap to install Perl modules

Tags: perl, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr

I'm trying to write a Perl script that will run as a mapper under Elastic MapReduce's Streaming capability. I'm trying to use Net::Amazon::S3 (or the supposedly more portable Amazon::S3) to do some extra I/O of files from and to S3. That module is not on the default AMI, so I'm trying to use CPAN in a bootstrap-action script to install it. The bootstrap script currently contains:

perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install(Amazon::S3)'

however, after 15 minutes the bootstrap action has still not completed, so I assume it is waiting for some kind of input. I've looked around but have not found any examples of bootstrap-action scripts that load Perl modules. Can someone advise me on that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Instead of speculating, grab the output!

Comment: Good point. The .../bootstrap-actions/1/stdout file contains a prompt from cpan asking whether to automatically configure things or do so manually one item at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an easier and faster way. It looks like most CPAN modules are also available by apt-get. I have a bootstrap action script that now says:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

source /etc/profile
# Make sure we have all of the dependencies in place for our Perl script.
sudo apt-get install -y libjson-perl
sudo apt-get install -y liburi-encode-perl
```

Note that this does not load the S3 module I asked about in the original question. I have changed my code so that I don't need that capability anymore. However, Net::Amazon::S3 is available as libnet-amazon-s3-perl so

```
sudo apt-get install -y libnet-amazon-s3-perl
```

should do the job.

Credit goes to http://www.deepakg.com/prog/2009/01/cpan-modules-on-ubuntu-apt-get-vs-perl-mcpan/ for the info.

Answer (score 1):

- Copy `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` from a machine with a configured `cpan`.
- Set `cpan` config option `prerequisites_policy` to `follow`.
- Set env var `PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can make this work by ssh-ing into the master node, running cpan there to get the config file, using s3cmd to put a copy of it back into S3 for future use, and having future elastic-mapreduce commands provide it as a cachefile.